# Long Focus Mitts for Punching and Kicking

Tags: training

I kind of hate holding the Muay Thai style kicking pads that most people seem to use for training punching and kicking combos. I much prefer the boxing style focus mitts with an open hand like these

[image: Focus Mitts]

but I recognize that the longer MT style pads are better for kicks. Every once in a while I see training footage of someone using a pad that seems like the perfect combination of the two. Here's Dominick Cruz's trainer using some.

https://www.instagram.com/p/Bp-bzaEnqUP/

That's exactly what I want, but I no amount of googling ever turns them up. Does anyone know what they're called or where I might buy some?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I provided some links to websites where you can get them. Ordering from Thailand will cost you shipping as well as customs if you are in USA or Canada. But you can look at them and order from mma stores in your country. I think most good stores will have these.

1. Here at [muaythaistuff.com](https://www.muaythaistuff.com/thai-pads.html?p=2) you will find the Top King and Fairtex ones. These are great.

[image]

[image]

[image]

2. At [muaythaifactory.com](https://www.muaythaifactory.com/muay-thai-training-gear.asp?page=2) you will find Top King, Fairtex, and Thaismai.
3. [Venum](https://www.venum.com/venum-elite-big-focus-mitts.html) has good ones too.

[image]

4. [And here is another](http://www.twinsfightgear.com/TWINS-FOCUS-MITTS)

Comment: To make images smaller, add an `s` (or `m`)  between the end of the URL and the .png… See edited answer.

Comment: You are most welcome. I edited the links as well.

Comment: Clearly your Google kung fu is greater than mine. I think the Venom one is exactly what Dom is using in the video. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it's helpful to others, Triumph United just released some of these.

https://www.triumphunited.com/equipment/tu-hybrid-focus-mitts-black.html